# Plain TeX end of proof macro

Tags: macros, plain-tex

I am writing a macro to typeset proofs of theorems.  By getting rid of irrelevant (for this question) things, it simplifies to

```
\def\demo#1\enddemo{\noindent{\it Proof.\quad}#1\quad\copy\cvdbox\medskip}
```

where `cvdbox` is a box which contains an end-of-proof symbol.  For example, let it be:

```
\newbox\cvdbox
\setbox\cvdbox=\hbox{\bf CVD}
```

The macro does it's job as expected, except when the proofs ends with a displayed equation, that is something in between double dollar signs. In fact, the `\cvdbox` is placed on a new line by itself, instead of being placed on the right of the last line.
I would like that, when the proof ends with a displayed formula, the `\cvdbox` is set at the end of the display, just before the closing double dollar signs.
For example, I would like that

```
\demo
 ...
$$\int_a^bf.$$
\enddemo
```

gets transformed into

```
\noindent{\it Proof.\quad}... $$\int_a^bf.\quad\copy\cvdbox$$\medskip}
```

instead of

```
\noindent{\it Proof.\quad}... $$\int_a^bf.$$\quad\copy\cvdbox\medskip}
```

How can I do?

Comment: it looks like you're using the ams-tex syntax.  putting the end-of-proof marker into the right place automatically is a hard problem, which is why, in *joy of tex* it's recommended to insert `\qed` manually.  if you really *are* using ams-tex, you could do worse than copying the definition of `\qed` and substituting your "cvd" content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you needn't to put the QED mark immediately after the formula in display line but aligned right in this line, then you can use this:

```
\input plipsum

\def\demo{\par\noindent{\it Proof.\quad}}
\def\enddemo{\ifdim\lastskip=0pt % after display
      \par \dimen0=\lastskip \removelastskip 
      \advance\dimen0 by\prevdepth \kern-\prevdepth
      \nointerlineskip \vbox to0pt{\vss\line{\hss\bf QED}}
      \vskip\dimen0
   \else \unskip \quad\hbox{\bf QED}\fi
   \medskip
}

\demo
\lipsum{1}
$$
\int_a^bf.
$$
\enddemo

\demo
\nopar\lipsum{1}
\enddemo

\end
```

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion you want to define a `\qedhere` macro to be used like

```
\input plipsum

\long\def\demo#1\enddemo{%
  \global\qedtrue
  \noindent{\it Proof.\quad}%
  #1%
  \ifqed\quad\copy\cvdbox\fi
  \medskip
}
\newif\ifqed
\def\qedhere{\global\qedfalse\rlap{\quad\copy\cvdbox}}

\newbox\cvdbox
\setbox\cvdbox=\hbox{\bf CVD}

\demo
\lipsum{1}
$$
\int_a^bf.\qedhere
$$
\enddemo

\demo
\nopar\lipsum{1}
\enddemo

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: that's really all that `\qed` does in ams-tex.  there's an `\if@qedhere` defined there, but if's never used in any useful way.  maybe something happened in `lamstex`, but i haven't got a copy here to check.

Comment: @egreg Good suggestion!

Comment: @barbarabeeton Looking at `lamstex` I see nothing anymore about 'qed'.